# How to generate a pre-filled fillable PDF, change its content and parse the content

Tags: javascript, java, xml, pdf

Could you please try to direct me which way should I be aiming in order to achieve the following high level requirement related to creating a fillable PDF for a user. The user can open this PDF, change some content, save the PDF, send it back to us via email and our system will parse the content and upload it to a database.

basic steps:
- the user clicks on a web button and the system behind this online web application sends an email to the user with a PDF document having all details from the user's saved application, e.g. full name, postcode, dob, answers to some questions (tickboxes), free text comments area
- the user opens this PDF, changes some details e.g. updates text in the comments area, unticks some check boxes, changes post code
- the user saves the changes and sends the PDF back to us.
- the system reads the PDF, parses the content and updates the data in a database.

Is the above possible? If so, please try to advise which technology can be used.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the other message, why send the filled PDF back? (well, unless you need a digitally signed version for your records).

Instead use the Submit function of PDF/Acrobat, which submits just the data. This is possible (among other ways) using HTML POST, and therefore working as if the data were sent by a HTML form. Updating the database should not be a big deal anymore in this case.

If you have to insist on sending back a filled form, there are AFAIK utilities which can extract the form data, and then, again, updating the database should not be difficult.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand why you want to email a PDF for a user to fill out and then try to parse it in the first place? Why not just make some sort of web app that prints nicely for this?

If you really need a PDF, you might want to design your form in TeX and use something like this [example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14842/creating-fillable-pdfs).